# pip install setup.py extras_require that referencences git+ssh and other extras_require

Tags: python, pip, packaging, setup.py, requirements

when I execute the command:

```
'pip install -e git+ssh://git@git.mycompany.de/myenvironment/myfolder/myproject.git@master#egg=myproject[myextras]'
```

it works like a charm. All the packages within [myextras] are getting installed.
For example let's assume my extras look like this (in myproject).

```
 .... extras_require={'myextras':['pandas~=1.0.3']} ....
```

pip successfully installs pandas.

But here it gets tricky: I have another project called "theotherone" which itself has extras_require specified in its setup.py.

```
.... extras_require={'externalextras':['myproject@git+ssh://git@git.mycompany.de/myenvironment/myfolder/myproject.git@master#egg=myproject[myextras]']} ....
```

When I try to install these extras with pip:

```
pip install -e .[externalextras]
```

It successfully installs myproject but skips all the defined packages in the "myextras". So pandas doesn't get installed.

How can I solve this is there any way? Or do I have to use the pip command at the top?